# Cannot get information on preview print from datagridview

Tags: vb.net, printing, datagridview, preview

Im using this cod to try to preview my print from datagridview:

```
Dim mRow As Integer = 0
Dim newpage As Boolean = True
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim custCells As Integer() = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    With DataGridView1
        Dim fmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)
        fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
        fmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
        Dim y As Single = e.MarginBounds.Top
        Do While mRow < .RowCount
            Dim row As DataGridViewRow = .Rows(mRow)
            Dim x As Single = e.MarginBounds.Left
            Dim h As Single = 0
            For Each cell As Integer In custCells
                Dim rc As RectangleF = New RectangleF(x, y, row.Cells(cell).Size.Width, row.Cells(cell).Size.Height)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc.Left, rc.Top, rc.Width, rc.Height)
                If (newpage) Then
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Columns(cell).HeaderText, .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                Else
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.Rows(row.Cells(cell).RowIndex).Cells(cell).FormattedValue.ToString(), .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                End If
                x += rc.Width
                h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
            Next
            newpage = False
            y += h
            mRow += 1
            If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
                e.HasMorePages = True
                mRow -= 1
                newpage = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Loop
        mRow = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

The thing is, when i try to preview, the information of my datagridview doesnt show on the preview, only the column names.

[image: Printscreen]

Some help? 
Thank you!

Comment: Have you debugged the code?  By that I mean actually stepped through it line by line and made sure that execution follows the expected path and that each variable is the expected value at each step?

Comment: yes i did that mate.

Comment: So does everything happen exactly as you expect when stepping through the code?